# Obtaining a bound on the differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I just need a little bit of help filling in the missing details in the following passage from Reddy (1986)'s *Applied Functional Analysis and Variational Methods in Engineering*

> Let $C_0[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions $u$ on [0,1] such
>   that $u(0)=u(1)=0$.  The differential operator $D\equiv \frac{d}{dx}$
>   is bounded below with respect to the $L_2$ norm in $C_0[0,1]$.  We
>   have $$u(x)=\int_0^x \frac{du}{dy} dy \leq \left[ \int_0^x
>  \left|\frac{du}{dy}\right|^2 dy \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
>
> $$\int_0^1|u(x)|^2dx\leq\int_0^1 \left| \frac{du}{dx}\right|^2 dx.$$

I'm not quite sure what property allows me to conclude the first inequality.  It almost looks like an application of Minkowski's inequality except for the fact that $\frac{du}{dy}\neq \left[ \left(\frac{du}{dy} \right)^2\right]^\frac{1}{2}$ (at least, not necessarily).  I'm also not sure how the second inequality was obtained from the first.

Any help filling in the gaps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first seems to be an application of Cauchy-Schwarz but I'm not $100\%$ sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is Holder (use Holder inequality with the functions $\frac{du}{dy}$ and the constant function $1$) combined with the fact that $x\leq 1$: $$\int_0^x \frac{du}{dy}dy\leq \int_0^x \left|\frac{du}{dy}\right|dy\leq \left(\int_0^x \left|\frac{du}{dy}\right|^2dy\right)^{1/2}x^{1/2}$$

Remark: This inequality is also known as [Poincaré inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality).

Comment: This almost makes sense.  But the left hand side of the inequality uses $\frac{du}{dy}$, not $\left| \frac{du}{dy}\right|$.  Unless it is somehow implicitly assumed that $\frac{du}{dy}>0$, I just can't see how we can conclude this.